# SSL error when installing Gradle during react-native run-android

Tags: java, android, ssl, gradle, react-native

I am following react-native official steps how to install and run app (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). Everything is fine (install react-native and other libraries, run ios version), but `react-native run-android` fails with following error. What comes to my mind is problem with OSX El Capitan and OpenSSL, but I tried to fix it few months ago and solved all issues. But i did not find anything for this specific error.
I tried to install gradle via `brew install gradle`, but react-native still try to install it again. Maybe there is a way how to tell react-native not to install it again?

Thanks for any help

```
22:23 $ react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:255)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:405)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:289)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:55)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
    ... 19 more
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on El Capitan, after I messed with OpenSSL. This means your Java certificate is screwed up.

In the end, I fixed the problem by reinstalling the JDK.

You can do this by first removing the current JDK under:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk`

Then run:

`sudo rm -rf jdk1.X.X_XX.jdk`

Install your version of JDK again, and everything should be working!

---

**Aside**

Other symptoms of this problem includes not being able to run any SSL-related 'fetch' functions. For instance, running the Android package manager will give you errors saying it couldn't fetch xml files from https servers.

Comment: replacing openjdk 7 with openjdk8 did it for me. Maybe a reinstall of openjdk7 also work, but I didn't tried it.
Thank you for this hint.